# openssl_verify , Warning: openssl_verify(): supplied key param cannot be coerced into a public key

Tags: php, openssl, signature, verify

I have this error with this file:

```
<?php
// $data and $signature are assumed to contain the data and the signature

$signature = null;
$toSign = "C:/Users/User/Desktop/xampp/htdocs/docum.docx";

$fp = fopen("key.pem", "r");
$priv_key = fread($fp, 8192);
fclose($fp);
$pkeyid = openssl_get_privatekey($priv_key);

openssl_sign($toSign, $signature, $pkeyid);

openssl_free_key($pkeyid);
echo($signature);
// fetch public key from certificate and ready it
$fp = fopen("C:/Users/User/Desktop/xampp/htdocs/pubkey.der", "r");
$cert = fread($fp, 8192);
fclose($fp);
$pubkeyid = openssl_get_publickey($cert);

// state whether signature is okay or not
$ok = openssl_verify($toSign, $signature, $pubkeyid);
if ($ok == 1) {
    echo "good";
} elseif ($ok == 0) {
    echo "bad";
} else {
    echo "ugly, error checking signature";
}
// free the key from memory
openssl_free_key($pubkeyid);
?>
```

how can I fix this error ?`...
I calculated the signature with the private key to the document, now I want to test it.
at first I created two php files , the first one that signed the document , the second occurred ke me signing . I just do not know how to take the signature from the first documento.Ho decided to put it all together to try ... How can I fix ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you *absolutely* certain that your public key file is shorter than 8192 bytes? If you're just looking to read a file into a variable use `file_get_contents()`, it's far simpler.
2. What did `openssl_get_publickey($cert)` return?
3. Based on the error you got it looks like OpenSSL expects PEM formatted keys, so you'll need to convert it.

Try:

```
function der2pem($der_data) {
   $pem = chunk_split(base64_encode($der_data), 64, "\n");
   $pem = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n".$pem."-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";
   return $pem;
}

$cert = der2pem(file_get_contents('C:/Users/User/Desktop/xampp/htdocs/pubkey.der'));

if( ! $pubkeyid = openssl_get_publickey($cert) ) {
    throw new \Exception(openssl_error_string());
}
```

Comment: this error:Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line' in C:\Users\User\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\verificaFirma.php:23 Stack trace: #0 {main} ... this is the code:$fp = fopen("key.pem", "r");$priv_key = fread($fp,100000);fclose($fp);$pkeyid =openssl_get_privatekey($priv_key);openssl_sign($toSign, $signature, $pkeyid);openssl_free_key($pkeyid);echo($signature);$cert=file_get_contents('C:/Users/User/Desktop/xampp/htdocs/pubkey.der');if( ! $pubkeyid =openssl_get_publickey($cert) ) {
    throw new \Exception(openssl_error_string());}

Comment: @hisecure Updated the answer.

Comment: now return this error with your code Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag'

Comment: @hisecure Can you post the PEM-formatted public key somewhere? At this point there's not much advice I can give without looking at the certificate.